# Ember.js: binding to dynamic form inputs

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to figure out the proper way to collect "variable" personalized data on a product.   The product has these personalized fields defined:

```
"personalization": [
  {
    "id": 234, 
    "maxlength": "128", 
    "prompt": "Text Line 1 (12 character limit)", 
    "required": "1"
  }, 
  {
    "id": 235, 
    "maxlength": "128", 
    "prompt": "Text Line 2 (12 character limit)", 
    "required": "1"
  }
],
```

Building a small form to collect that input would be fairly straightforward, except that personalized data can be different for each quantity.  So if I order 2 of this item, it can have personalization:

```
FIRST ITEM
Text Line 1: Yarr
Text line 2: Matey

SECOND ITEM
Text Line 1: Swab
Text line 2: The poop deck
```

So basically the set of personalized fields needs to repeat for each quantity.

I've got the form built using a computed property:

```
personalizedForm: computed('quantity', function() {
    let q = get(this, 'quantity');
    let persform = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        persForm.push(get(this, 'model.personalization'));
    } 
    return persForm;
}),
```

with this template:

```
{{#each personalizedForm as |quantity index|}}
    Item {{add index 1}}
    <ul>
        {{#each quantity as |set|}}
            <li class="label">{{set.prompt}}</li>
            <li class="field">{{input value=????}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{/each}}
```

And that shows a form like the image below.  So that's great.  But I just can't figure out exactly what to bind each form field to, and *how*.  I imagine the "mut" and "get" helpers are the ticket, but I don't even know how to set up the object to save the data to.

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think I have this somewhat figured out. On the controller there's a property and a computed property that updates it if/when the quantity changes:

```
persModel: [], // will contain dynamic model

persModelUpdated: computed('quantity', function() {

    let persModel = this.get('persModel');
    let persPrompts = get(this, 'model.personalization');

    // loop thru quantities
    for (let i = 0; i < get(this, 'quantity'); i++) {
        // if persModel does not have this set of prompts, push in a copy
        if (!persModel.objectAt(i)) {  
            let copySet = Ember.copy(persPrompts, { 'deep': true });
            persModel.pushObject(copySet);
        }
    }

    return persModel;
})
```

In the template the fields are written out dynamically based on the computed property.  I'm using the mut and get helpers to update a 'value' field within each set.

```
{{#each persModelUpdated as |thisQty index|}}
    Item {{add index 1}}
    <ul>
        {{#each thisQty as |persSet|}}
        <li>{{persSet.prompt}}</li>
        <li>{{input value=(mut (get persSet 'value'))}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Instead of `{{input value=(mut (get persSet 'value'))}}` you can try `{{input value=persSet.value)}}`

Comment: Right - yeah the mut and get helpers are unnecessary.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sur to understand you want to find a way to get all the value from the dynamic form ?

You can try to serialize your form.
You have to put the balise form before and after your each like so

```
<form id="my_form">
 {{#each personalizedForm as |quantity|}}
  Item {{add index 1}}
  <ul>
    {{#each quantity as |set|}}
        <li class="label">{{set.prompt}}</li>
        <li class="field">{{input value=????}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
 {{/each}}
<form>
```

and then in your component .js you can get them by doing
 `const formArray = Ember.$('#my_form').serializeArray();` 
 to get a array or
 `const form = Ember.$('#my_form').serialize();` to get a object